# Visual Studio 2019: Break points do not break

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have a very strange behavior in Visual Studio and I can't explain it.

In a bigger project I have a class, that looks something like this:

```
Public Class DatabaseDescription
    Inherits DatabaseDescriptor

    Private _tableNames As List(Of String)

    ...

    Public ReadOnly Property TableNames As IEnumerable(Of String)
        Get
            If (_tableNames Is Nothing) Then
                _tableNames = Me.GetTableNames
            End If

            Return _tableNames
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Function GetTableNames() As IEnumerable(Of String)
        Dim result As New List(Of String)

        ...

        Stop
        Debug.Print("Hallo")

        ...

        result.Add(tableName & "_Test")

        ...
        Return result
    End Function

    ...

End Class
```

The class variable `_tableNames` is only used in the property `TableNames`, nowhere else.

I set a break point in the function `GetTableNames` right at the beginning, so, if this function ever gets called, my break point should be hit.

I set a break point right at the beginning of the property `TableNames`.

I put an explicit `Stop` and a `Debug.Print` in the function `GetTableNames`.

I added a "_Test" to every table name, just to be sure that I'm working with the right code.

And guess what... when running my code `TableNames` gets filled, without my break points ever being hit. The explicit `Stop` didn't work either. But I see my `Debug.Print` and every table name has a "_Test" at the end.

All the projects in my solution are in debug configuration. When I delete the library in question from the output folder, it gets re-created. Restarting Visual Studio didn't help either. Change the "_Test" to "_Test2" and changing the `Debug.Print` text have an immediate effect, but the break points and the explicit `Stop` won't work. Other break points in the same class work, eventhe one in the property, when I access it the first time on purpose.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently some feature or function of Visual Studio got the value of `TableNames` for Intellisense reasons and for that they probably ignore break points or explicit `Stop`s.

After closing a few of Visual Studios windows (like "Watch", "Local" or "Diagnostic Tools") the problem vanished.